# Set the PSModulePath variable on Linux - PowerShell 7

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I am trying to update the PSModulePath variable on Linux (CentOS 7.9). I have tried:

```
# Check current path(s)
$env:PSModulePath
/opt/microsoft/powershell/7-lts/Modules

# Update the variable
$env:PSModulePath += ":/opt/MyModules"
# Confirm the update
$env:PSModulePath
/opt/microsoft/powershell/7-lts/Modules:/opt/MyModules
```

All working OK. Now I try to relaunch PowerShell:

```
exit
pwsh
$env:PSModulePath
/opt/microsoft/powershell/7-lts/Modules
```

The setting does not persist. How can I fix this?

Using:
PowerShell 7

Linux CentOS 7.9

Comment: I'm not as familiar with Linux as I am with Windows, but if PowerShell isn't your default shell, you probably have to set the psmodulepath outside of powershell, then invoke pwsh. In a lot of Linux discussions, I see login shell scripts with statements like `FOO=BAR; EXPORT FOO`; you may need to do something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning to `$env:PSModulePath` sets the *process*-scoped copy of the `PSModulePath` environment variable, which is by definition *not* persisted; it disappears when the process terminates.

To make *persistent* changes, you have two options:

- Use your *system's* features for defining *persistent* environment variables.

  - For instance, for Ubuntu see [this askubuntu.com answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/26411/225111).
- Add the modification statement to your PowerShell [`$PROFILE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) file (there are multiple profiles, based on whether they apply to all vs. the current user, and all vs. specific PowerShell host environments).